# Excel forumla to look down a column for a specific value and copy across to a cell in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there anyway for a users to specify a value to be looked for down a certain column and if found be copied across to a cell in another column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the most basic operation of excel. I almost feel guilty about answering it - no offense.

```
=IF(E1=C4,C4,"")
```

autofill that down a column and you'll have your solution

[image: Seriously]

Are you familiar with the term autofill?

Answer (score 2):

yes! it's called [vlookup](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm)......